# How to execute function "y" when function "x" is executed in PHP

Tags: php

I have three PHP files which contain mail functions in different places. This was an initial implementation. Now I need to show the mail sent count and other results in my application log. I created a few lines of statement which are shown below. I use a simple increment++ operator to increment the values retrieved from a database:

```
// Talking to database
$previous_val = $from_db; // Getting previous value stores
if(!empty($previous_val)|| $previous_val == 0 ){
    $previous_val++;
    // Storing previous value here
}
else{
    $previous_val = 1;
    // Storing previous value here
}
```

The problem is that I already use a few other statements for other purposes, when the mail function is run as below:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
    // Other statements for other purposes are here
}
```

I don't want to include the counter statement in the three files. So I want to make a general counter function and call it inside the mail block along with the other statement, as shown here:

```
function mail_counter(){
    // Talking to database
    $previous_val = from_db; // Getting previous value stores
    if(!empty($previous_val)|| $previous_val == 0 ){
        $previous_val++;
        // Storing previous value here
    }
    else{
        $previous_val = 1;
        //Storing previous value here
    }
}
```

I want to use the above function in all mail functions like this:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)){
    // Other statements for other purpose are here
    mail_counter();
}
```

**Everything works fine. However, I want to further minimize the coding.** Is this possible? Can I go further by tieing the `mail_counter()` function with the `mail` function so whenever a `mail` function is called, the `mail_counter()` function can also be called? Like binding in jQuery for example. I don't know whether it is possible?

I wanted to do the same for my custom functions too. Like when function `x` is called I need to execute function `y` too. There are lot of repeating codes. My main objective is to create good code without code repeat and with a reasonable amount of lines. Can anybody help me regarding this problem?

Comment: You should have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern if you're trying to learn "good coding" there are at least 10 default ways to improve your example by using design patterns.

Comment: @sharpner thanks for the link. i tried few books that couldn't help me well. so if i get solution based on my problem above i think it will be helpful in understanding. So i posted this question. In fact i have implemented the above in oops design only.

Comment: maybe this tutorial will help you proceed: http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/03/30/php-object-oriented-programming-for-absolute-beginners/ 

what you are doing is not object oriented development, since you're not using classes or interfaces or interheritance =)

Comment: No i have classes. I have two classes in two file and helper class with the above mail_counter() function in another seperate file. I have included this two class in the mail file. I just showed the code example without classes.

Comment: the `mail` function doesnt provide any hooks you could tie into. The "nice" way to do this would be to create your own "mail" function to be used in your code. You could then change that function to do what ever you need in addition to calling mail. (BTW: OOP is much more complex than just having classes in files ;) )

Comment: @ToBe thanks. This is what people also saying as "just having class is not complete OOP" That is the reason i have asked the question to hook "y" function when "x" is called at one place alone not everywhere by using good OOP desing. Do you have any example about this?

Comment: This is a far to complex topic to be discussed on Stackoverflow. But there are many nice books on OOP and Patterns. The "Head First" Series is an easy approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

There is, to my knowledge (and I asked this a few years back) no way to bind observers to function calls.  The only way (and a very elegant way) is just to write your own function or method, and pass the same variables you would to `mail()`, and have that function or method call `mail()`.  Generally, mail is an "atomic" function and most modern platforms don't call it directly in their coding but rather have a Mail class of some sort so as to pre-configure before send, handle logging etc.

Perhaps you could call your function `enhanced_mail()` and use it to handle sending attachments, bcc's and etc..  There are classes out there that do that, but I wanted to more directly answer your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Havent't thought this over much, but perhaps you could use something like an `Cascade` class with a callback(s) option.

```
class Cascade {
    private $callbacks = [ ];

    public function addCallback($callable) {
        if (is_callable($callable)) {
            $this->callbacks[] = $callable;
        } else {
            $test = [ $this, $callable ];
            if (method_exists($test)) {
                $this->callbacks[]  = $test;
            }
        }
    }

    function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $ret = call_user_func_array($name, $arguments);
        foreach ($this->callbacks as $callback) {
            $callback($name, $arguments);
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

In this case you would:

```
$mailer = new Cascade();
$mailer->addCallback(function() { ... });

$mailer->mail(arguments);
```

You might also place the most common functions inside Cascade (or a subclass of Cascade) and use a static method:

```
Cascade::build('callback1')->mail(...arguments...)
```

or adding a default callback in the build call of a specific subclass:

```
LoggingCascade::build()->mail(...arguments...)
```

A cascade can call anything as long as it's defined, thanks to the magic __call method.

With the same logic you can extend the class to add e.g. requisites (a callable that is called *before* the real function is, and under certain circumstances may even abort the call - you make a requisite return true or false and act accordingly) or filters (something that gets `$ret` and manipulates it).